# How to listen mysql database changes in Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

Actually i have a service that execute an Async task checking via id GET in php webservice is there a better way to achieve this? 
mysql does not notify on changes
im new and i have no idea of how to make a proper listener ;

my code:

```
    import android.app.IntentService;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.media.RingtoneManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.os.Looper;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;



    import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.ActividadPrincipal;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.Adaptadores.Adaptador_Pedido_Hecho;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.Fragmento_Menu;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.MyApplication;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.R;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.SharedPref;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.modelo.PedidoHecho;
    import com.fda.agil_eat.tools.Constantes;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Timer;
    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class RSSPullService extends Service {
        // constant
        public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000; // 10 seconds
        public RequestQueue mQueue;
        private Timer mtimer;


// run on another Thread to avoid crash
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private Handler segundoHandler = new Handler();
        private Timer mTimer = null;
        public TimeDisplayTimerTask tsk = new TimeDisplayTimerTask();

public static String nombredelivery;
public static String itemspedido;
public static String aclaracionespedido;
public static String direccionpedido;
public static String telefonopedido;
public static String montopedido;
public static String iddelivery;
public static int cantPedidos = 0;
public static boolean enviapedido=false;
public static  ArrayList<String> listapedidos = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> listapedidosaborrar = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<PedidoHecho> listadoPedidos = new ArrayList<PedidoHecho>();
public static Adaptador_Pedido_Hecho adaptador_pedido_hecho=new Adaptador_Pedido_Hecho(listadoPedidos);

public Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do Something
        task();

    }
};
public Runnable myRunnable2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do Something

        task2();
    }
};
class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(myRunnable);
        segundoHandler.post(myRunnable2);

    }

}


public static String tiempo;
public void task() {
  if (enviapedido) {
        new AscyncPedido().execute();
        enviapedido=false;
    }

}
    public List<String> colaAsync = new ArrayList<>();
public void task2(){
    ArrayList<String> listapedidos2=listapedidos;
    if (listapedidos2.size()>0) {
        for (String ped : listapedidos2) {
            final String idpedido = ped;
            int e = listapedidos2.indexOf(ped);
            String estado = "";
            for (PedidoHecho p:listadoPedidos) {
                if (p.id.equals(idpedido)){
                    estado=p.estado;
                }

            }
            if (estado.toLowerCase().equals("enviado")) {
               if (colaAsync.indexOf(ped)==(-1)){
                   new AscyncAprobacion().execute(idpedido);
                   colaAsync.add(ped);
               }

            }
        }
        boolean todos_tienen_respuesta=true;
        for (PedidoHecho unpedido:listadoPedidos) {
            if(unpedido.estado.toLowerCase().equals("enviado")){
                todos_tienen_respuesta=false;
            }
        }
        if (todos_tienen_respuesta) {
            if (listapedidosaborrar.size() > 0) {
                for (String i : listapedidosaborrar) {
                    try {
                        listapedidos.remove(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       // //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}



public class AscyncAprobacion extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
      //       boolean HayPedido = false;
     //       int contador=0;
    //        boolean notificada=false;
            @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... params) {
        Thread
                splashTread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {




                    try {

                      getapr(params[0]);



                                sleep(3000);


                    }catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    } finally {

                    }
                }


        };
        splashTread.start();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // FragmentoInicio.this.adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

    public void getapr(final String idped) {
boolean continuar = false;
final String idpedido = idped;
for (PedidoHecho pedi : listadoPedidos) {
    if (pedi.id.equals(idpedido)) {
        if (pedi.estado.toLowerCase().equals("enviado")) {
            continuar = true;
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

}
if (continuar) {

    try {
        if (mQueue != null) {
            mQueue.cancelAll(this.getClass().getName());
        }
    } catch (Exception exx) {
        Log.e("Cancel queue", exx.toString());
    }

    try {


        String url = Constantes.Aprobado + "?id=" + idpedido;
        Log.e("apr", url);
        StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                        // String aprobado;
                        String respuesta = obj.getString("aprobada");
                        switch (respuesta.toUpperCase()) {
                            case "SI":

                                Handler mHandler1 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                mHandler1.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            if (mQueue != null) {
                                                mQueue.cancelAll(this.getClass().getName());
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("Cancel queue", e.toString());
                                        }
                                        try {
                                            String url = Constantes.Tiempo + "?id=" + idpedido;
                                            Log.e("time", url);

                                            StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                    boolean existe = false;
                                                    try {
                                                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                                                        String respuesta = obj.getString("tiempo");
                                                        Log.e("tiempo", respuesta);
                                                        tiempo = respuesta;
                                                        int i = listapedidos.indexOf(idpedido);

                                                        for (String it : listapedidosaborrar) {
                                                            if (it.equals(idpedido)) {
                                                                existe = true;
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                        if (!existe) {
                                                            try {
                                                                String est = "";
                                                                listapedidosaborrar.add(idpedido);
                                                                for (PedidoHecho pp : listadoPedidos) {
                                                                    if (pp.id.equals(idpedido)) {
                                                                        est = pp.estado;
                                                                        pp.estado = "Aprobado";
                                                                        pp.detalleestado = tiempo;
                                                                        pp.horapedido = getCurrentTimeStamp();
                                                                    }

                                                                }


                                                                adaptador_pedido_hecho.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                                                if (est.toLowerCase().equals("enviado")) {
                                                                    Bitmap aBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                                                                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(RSSPullService.this.getApplicationContext())
                                                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.minilogo).setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
                                                                            .setTicker("Noticias de tu Pedido!!")
                                                                            .setContentTitle("Noticias de tu Pedido!!")
                                                                            .setContentText("Tu pedido fue aprobado!!\n" + "Llegada aproximada en : " + tiempo)
                                                                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                            .setTicker("Tu pedido fue aprobado!!\n" + "Llegada aproximada en : " + tiempo)
                                                                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Noticias de tu Pedido!!"))
                                                                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Tu pedido fue aprobado!!\n" + "Llegada aproximada en : " + tiempo))
                                                                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                                                                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                                                                            .setVibrate(new long[]{1, 1, 1})
                                                                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                                                                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                                                                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                                                                    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                                                    Notification notify = new Notification();
                                                                    notify.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
                                                                    Random random = new Random();
                                                                    notificationmanager.notify(random.nextInt(), builder.build());
                                                                    new NotificarInforme().execute(idpedido);
                                                                }
                                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                                // //e.printStackTrace();
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        // //e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                            stringRequest2.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, 6, 6));
                                            if (mQueue == null) {
                                                mQueue = MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                        .getRequestQueue();
                                                mQueue.add(stringRequest2);
                                            } else {
                                                mQueue.add(stringRequest2);
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("EX", e.toString());

                                        }
                                    }

                                });


                                break;
                            case "NO":

                                Handler mHandler2 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                mHandler2.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        try {
                                            if (mQueue != null) {
                                                mQueue.cancelAll(this.getClass().getName());
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("Cancel queue", e.toString());
                                        }
                                        try {
                                            String url = Constantes.Tiempo + "?id=" + idpedido;
                                            Log.e("time", url);

                                            StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                    boolean existe = false;
                                                    try {
                                                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                                                        String respuesta = obj.getString("tiempo");
                                                        Log.e("tiempo", respuesta);
                                                        tiempo = respuesta;
                                                        int i = listapedidos.indexOf(idpedido);

                                                        for (String it : listapedidosaborrar) {
                                                            if (it.equals(idpedido)) {
                                                                existe = true;
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                        if (!existe) {
                                                            try {
                                                                String est = "";
                                                                listapedidosaborrar.add(idpedido);
                                                                for (PedidoHecho pp : listadoPedidos) {
                                                                    if (pp.id.equals(idpedido)) {
                                                                        est = pp.estado;
                                                                        pp.estado = "Rechazado";
                                                                        pp.horapedido = getCurrentTimeStamp();
                                                                        if (tiempo.equals(" ")) {
                                                                            pp.detalleestado = "El Lugar lo Rechazo...";
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            pp.detalleestado = tiempo;
                                                                        }

                                                                    }

                                                                }


                                                                adaptador_pedido_hecho.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                                                if (est.toLowerCase().equals("enviado")) {
                                                                    Bitmap aBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

                                                                    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(RSSPullService.this.getApplicationContext())
                                                                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.minilogo).setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
                                                                            .setTicker("Noticias de tu Pedido!!")
                                                                            .setContentTitle("Noticias de tu Pedido!!")
                                                                            .setContentText("Tu pedido fue Rechazado...\n" + "El Local / Establecimiento rechazo tu pedido")
                                                                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                                            .setTicker("Tu pedido fue Rechazado...\n" + "El Local / Establecimiento rechazo tu pedido")
                                                                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Noticias de tu Pedido!!"))
                                                                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Tu pedido fue Rechazado...\n" + "El Local / Establecimiento rechazo tu pedido"))
                                                                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                                                                            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                                                                            .setVibrate(new long[]{1, 1, 1})
                                                                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                                                                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                                                                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                                                                    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                                                    Notification notify = new Notification();
                                                                    notify.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
                                                                    Random random = new Random();
                                                                    notificationmanager.notify(random.nextInt(), builder.build());
                                                                    new NotificarInforme().execute(idpedido);
                                                                }
                                                            } catch (Exception e) {


                                                                //           //e.printStackTrace();
                                                            }

                                                        }
                                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                        //        //e.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                            stringRequest2.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, 6, 6));
                                            if (mQueue == null) {
                                                mQueue = MyApplication.getInstance()
                                                        .getRequestQueue();
                                                mQueue.add(stringRequest2);
                                            } else {
                                                mQueue.add(stringRequest2);
                                            }
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("EX", e.toString());

                                        }
                                    }

                                });


                                break;
                            default:
                                Handler mHandler3 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                                mHandler3.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                            getapr(idped);


                                    }
                                });
                                break;
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //  //e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        getapr(idped);  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        stringRequest1.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15000, 6, 6));
        if (mQueue == null) {
            mQueue = MyApplication.getInstance()
                    .getRequestQueue();
            mQueue.add(stringRequest1);
        } else {
            mQueue.add(stringRequest1);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("EX", ex.toString());

    }
}
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: sorry for my crappy English {}

Comment: You are right MYSQL does no notify anybody of changes. If you want that to happen, you will have to write something that will do that for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL database change makes request to receive data to android via GCM or any other service. Which is reliable to you.

Comment: could u give an example or a link explaining this?? im pretty new

Comment: Integrate GCM Notification in your phone and when database change make a call to push notification from server side. At android side receive notificationID and based on that make a api call to refresh. check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/.